# Regex to Match Complex Where Clause for Certian Table

Tags: c#, sql, regex, where-clause

I have a program that takes restricted SQL Server WHERE clauses and removes sectiona that are targeting a certian table. An example of such a where clause is

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y')

I need to strip out all portions of the query that are using table `Episode` and take account of `(`, `)` to enclose statements and also square braces for field names etc. So to do this I have

```
private string BuildResourceWhereClauses(string whereClauses, string episodeTable)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(
        $"AND\\s+\\(*\\[*{episodeTable}\\]*\\.\\[*\\w+\\]*\\s*(=|<>|<=|>=)(\\s*\\'*(NULL|\\S+|\\((.*?)\\)+)\\'*\\s*\\)*){{1}}",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string tmp = r.Replace(whereClauses, String.Empty).Trim();
    return $" {tmp}";
}
```

This works well, returning

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null)

But now, I have been ask to extend this so that we allow all of the SQL WHERE clause syntax. So we now could have a where clause like

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y') AND (Episode.Paste = 'Y') AND [Episode].[Source] = '%6' AND [Episode].[TFC] NOT IN ('LWC', 'POD')

That we have to "parse", so I have amended the above method to

```
private string BuildResourceWhereClauses(string whereClauses, string episodeTable)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(
        $"AND\\s+\\(*\\[*{episodeTable}\\]*\\.\\[*\\w+\\]*\\s*(=|<>|<=|>=|LIKE|IN|NOT IN|IS|BETWEEN\\s+\\w+\\s+AND)(\\s*\\'*(NULL|\\S+|\\((.*?)\\)+)\\'*\\s*\\)*){{1}}",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string tmp = r.Replace(whereClauses, String.Empty).Trim();
    return $" {tmp}";
}
```

using `episodeTable = "Episode"` I get returned

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) 'POD')

This missing matches `AND (Episode.Paste = 'Y')`, `AND [Episode].[Source] = '%6'` and `AND [Episode].[TFC] NOT IN ('LWC', 'POD')`.

1. What is wrong with the regex how can I amend it to return what I want?
2. Rather than make this regex anymore complex, can we simplify it?

Thanks for your time.

---

The answer below strips out some functionality I had in before (my fault for not stipulating that I needed to keep it! and also what makes this so hard - to capture all cases"). So I need to match this string

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) 
>   AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y') AND Episode.FRC BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND Episode.Dt between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27' 
>   AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y' AND Episode.TFC IS NOT LIKE '655r%') 
>   AND (Episode.Paste = 'Y') AND [Episode].[Source] IS NOT LIKE '%6' AND [Episode].[TFC] NOT IN ('LWC', 'POD') AND [Episode].[TFC] IS NULL

So in C#, I need the following code

```
string whereClaues = 
    "AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) " + 
    "AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y') AND Episode.FRC BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND Episode.Dt between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27' " +
    "AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) AND ([Episode].[YN] = 'Y' AND Episode.TFC IS NOT LIKE '655r%') " +
    "AND (Episode.Paste = 'Y') AND [Episode].[Source] IS NOT LIKE '%6' AND [Episode].[TFC] NOT IN ('LWC', 'POD') AND [Episode].[TFC] IS NULL";
string tmp = r.Replace(whereClauses, String.Empty).Trim();
```

To give `tmp` as

> AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null) AND (Util.Source='IP%' AND Util.ReqType = 'IP') AND (Util.Epinum is null)

Stripping out all of the `Episode` clauses including `BETWEEN` statements and `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL` statements.

Is have

```
AND\s+\(*\[*Episode\]*\.\[*\w+\]*\s*(<>|[><]?=|(?:NOT\s+)?IN|(?:IS\s+)?LIKE|(?:IS\s+NOT\s+)?LIKE|BETWEEN(\s*\'*(\((.*?)\)+|NULL|\S+)\'*\s*\)*)AND)(\s*\'*(\((.*?)\)+|NULL|\S+)\'*\s*\)*)
```

But this is not matching

> Episode.TFC IS NULL

Comment: `What is wrong with the regex?` You're using regular expressions to modify SQL, which is an awful hack. Why can't you just modify the SQL?

Comment: The SQL comes in from user input. This where clause is used in one CTE query to create a tmp table, which is subsequently joined with another. I need to strip out the `Episode` parts of the where clause to use in the subsequent join query.


As with all things like this, why I am using this method is not always clear. I am using a regex here because it seems like a convenient way to do what I want without writing a full parser - which would be a lot more work.

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/ktjzlb/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I like that, please make a brief answer and I will accept. I think this might help someone else in the future.

Comment: Posted with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks you very much for your time, but I had forgot to stipulate that I needed to maintain my existing functionality _as well_. That is match `Episode.TT IS NULL` and `BETWEEN` statements. Also `IS LIKE` and `IS NOT LIKE` as in the updated question. Any chance you can come to my aid again? I will bounty it later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may extend your pattern in the following way:

```
$@"AND\s+\(*\[*{episodeTable}\]*\.\[*\w+\]*\s*(<>|[><]?=|(?:NOT\s+)?IN)(\s*\'*(\((.*?)\)+|NULL|\S+)\'*\s*\)*)"
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ktjzlb/1/).

**Details**

- `AND` - a substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\(*` - 0+ `(` chars
- `\[*` -  0+ `[` chars
- `Episode` - name of the table
- `\]*` - 0+ `]` chars
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `\[*` - 0+ `[` chars
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\]*` - 0+ `]` chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(<>|[><]?=|(?:NOT\s+)?IN)` - Group 1: `<>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=`, `NOT IN` or `IN`
- `(\s*\'*(\((.*?)\)+|NULL|\S+)\'*\s*\)*)` - Group 2:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
  - `\'*` - 0+ `'` chars
  - `(\((.*?)\)+|NULL|\S+)` - Group 3:

    - `\(` - a `(`
    - `(.*?)` - Group 4: any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible
    - `\)+` - 1+ `)` chars
    - `|` - or
    - `NULL` - a `NULL` substring
    - `|` - or
    - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `\'*` - 0+ `'` chars
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\)*` - 0+ `)` chars.

Comment: Pain in the rear, but I forgot parts like `AND [Episode].[Source] IS LIKE '%6'` and `AND [Episode].[Source] IS NOT LIKE '%6'`. Also, in group 3 we might have `NOT NULL` can you advise on my update `AND\s+\(*\[*Episode\]*\.\[*\w+\]*\s*(<>|[><]?=|(?:NOT\s+)?IN|(?:IS\s+)?LIKE)(\s*\'*(\((.*?)\)+|IS\s+(?:NOT\s+)?\s+NULL|\S+)\'*\s*\)*)` my attempt at adding support for IS NULL and IS NOT NULL does not work.